# What does "For every person shot in a mass killing" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I don't find any connection between this phrase and the idea in the previous sentence. Does it mean "**Between 1979 and today, there was 1 mass killing in which ALL of the people were shot**"?

"Australia’s 104 victims of mass shootings represent a small fraction of all people intentionally shot dead in Australia between 1979 and today. **For every person shot in a mass killing**, 139 others commit suicide or are murdered with guns in incidents in which fewer than five people die (most commonly one or two are killed)."

Source: http://fortune.com/2017/10/04/las-vegas-shooting-Australia-gun-control-laws/

Answer (score 3):

No. It is expressing a numerical proportion.

It is saying that 139 times as many people were killed by suicide or small incidents as in mass shootings.

It is common way of expressing such a proportion: for each (or every) X, there are *n* Y's, where *n* is some large number.

Comment: So it means "Between 1979 and today, there were 104 x 139 (=14456) people killed"?

Comment: +1. 14456  ... who were killed, or who killed themselves. But the statistic is qualified: "in incidents in which fewer than five people die"